# What is the constraint to force a column of a table to be a member of another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm designing a basic data base for the bank. I wondered what is the best way to add a constraint for each manager of a bank should be an employee of that bank?

Here is data structure so far:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Employee (
  2          BSB#            CHAR(6),                  /* Bank BSB number            */
  3          E#              CHAR(5)         NOT NULL, /* Employee number            */
  4          Name            VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Employee name              */
  5          DOB             Date,                     /* Date of birth              */
  6          Address         VARCHAR2(50),             /* Home address               */
  7          Sex             CHAR,                     /* M-Male, F-Female           */
  8          Salary          NUMBER(7,2),              /* Salary                     */
  9          Supervisor#     CHAR(5),                  /* Supervisor number          */
 10          CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY(BSB#, E#),
 11          CONSTRAINT Employee_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (BSB#, Supervisor#) REFERENCES Employee(BSB#, E#),
 12          CONSTRAINT Employee_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (BSB#) REFERENCES Bank (BSB#)
 13  );


CREATE TABLE Bank (
  2          BSB#            CHAR(6)         NOT NULL, /* Bank BSB number            */
  3          Name            VARCHAR2(40)    NOT NULL, /* Bank name                  */
  4          Address         VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL, /* Bank location              */
  5          Manager#        CHAR(5)         NOT NULL, /* Department manager number  */
  6          MSDate          DATE,                     /* Manager start date         */
  7          Phone#          VARCHAR2(15)    NOT NULL, /* Contact phone number       */
  8          CONSTRAINT Bank_PK PRIMARY KEY(BSB#),
  9          CONSTRAINT Bank_CK1 UNIQUE(Name)
 10  );
```

Comment: can you share you schema structure so far?

Comment: @Mureinik Yes I just edited my question.

Comment: It is interesting that you use `#` in columns names (not often done) to represent "number" and then have the type of that column be CHAR.  I suggest you change these to integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to make sure that a manager is a valid employee, you could use a simple foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE bank 
ADD CONSTRAINT bank_manager_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (manager#) REFERENCES employee(e#)
```

If you want to ensure that the bank manager is indeed an employee of **the same bank**, you'd need a fancier foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE bank 
ADD CONSTRAINT bank_manager_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (manager#, bsb#) REFERENCES employee(e#, bsb#)
```

Comment: Since the PK on Employee is `BSB#, E#`, the fancier notation will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for a foreign key.  There's a chicken-and-egg problem here.  Each employee refers to a bank via the `Employee.BSB#` number column, but each bank refers to an employee via `Bank.Manager#`.

I think you might do better with a separate table `BankManager` containing a `BSB#` and `Manager#` columns, plus the `MSDate` value.

Anyway, in most DBMS, you can't create a table `Employee` with FK constraints to table `Bank` before table `Bank` exists, nor vice versa.  So, with the two table design, you will probably have to create one of the tables without its FK constraints, and then add the FK constraints with ALTER TABLE.

With the three table design, you can create `Bank`, then `Employee`, then `BankManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not put manager stuff into the bank table, because a manager is an employee. So you have two types of employees, manageres and regular employees. Then this boils down to generalization/specialization design.

You can either add a flag (is_manager) in the Employee Table, or create another table Manager. In either case, the fact that this guy works at a bank is then a simple foreign key.

As for the qestion in the title `What is the constraint to force a column of a table to be a member of another table?` I  assume that you refer to the *value* of a column. In that case the answer is: you make a foreign key *from* `another table` to `a table`.